# Modify field names in REST export

Tags: views, 8

I want to use a custom field in my Views REST export, but rather than having "nothing": "My custom text", I would like "mycustomtext": "My custom text". Is there a way to do this from within the UI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Serializer settings:* **force using field & json**

*Show:* **fields**

*Show settings:* type an alias for each field

Above settings are shown in the images below

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Despite “no code answer” requested, it’s also quite easy to provide your own Normalizer class if this doesn’t exactly suit.